# Free space created for installation of Ubuntu 'unusable'

Tags: system-installation, 18.10

System Configuration:

- Ubuntu - 18.10
- Boot Mode - Legacy

The bootable USB was created using `rufus`. I freed up 200 GB for the installation. When I select 'something else' the freed space shows up as unusable.
What to do ?

[image]

Comment: How did you clear the 200G space that's supposed to be unallocated? Try creating a temporary NTFS partition on it and see what errors may occur.

Comment: Partition was created using Windows partition manager

Comment: Did you try and create a NTFS partition?

Comment: Exit out of the installer, drop into "Try Ubuntu" mode (it happens when you exit the installer).  Run `gparted`, then go to View > Device Information.  A new panel on the left will show up.  What does it say for "Partition table" in there?  MBR or GPT?

Answer (score 3):

With the classic MBR, you cannot allocate more than four primary partitions, in your case, you can only expand or delete sda4 and create an extended partition. In your case, converting sda4 from primary to extended will permit to create any logical partitions that you may require.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GParted if you do not like the terminal, it's the GUI option, where you can see all your partitions and do what you need in a graphical way. It is in the Ubuntu application store

You can format the partition from the terminal.
Entering as super user, in tmp folder,
mkfs is used to format partitions, it will show formatting options

**See partition table:**

With the command fdisk -l we can see how the partitions are distributed.

We can use the fdisk command and it will list all the disks.

We can also use fdisk / dev / xvd to enter a specific disk.

Remember, the discs are the ones that do not have a number.

***Types of Partitions:***

There are two types of partition tables:

The traditional one that allows 4 primary partitions and many logical ones (the logical partitions serve as containers for more partitions).

`gpt` that allows to have many more partitions.

***Create partition***

We execute fdisk / dev / xvd to enter the disk.

sudo fdisk / dev / sdX
Where "X" is the drive letter (like sda ​​or sdb depending on the drive).

n => Create new Partition (Then create what you need)

t => Specify type (NTFS is 07 , you can take a look at the list with L)

w => Write the changes to disk and exit

Change partition type
We execute fdisk / dev / xvd to enter the disk.
We select the partition number.
We select t
We choose the partition type number.

**Save the changes**

With `w` we keep the changes we make, if we leave without saving the configuration we do, it will not be written to the disk.

Then I have to mount the partition:
mount

Comment: This won't work if they are using an MBR-style partition table

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way.
I tried to install the ubuntu in my Sony Vaio's laptop. But for some reason I was unable to use the unallocated space which I had created for ubuntu installation using **disk management** in windows 10.
The free space was unusable.
I erased windows 10 and installed ubuntu. But I was unable to partition my 500GB hard disk in ubuntu. My total 500GB was taken just for the ubuntu software and I was unable to partition it to create drives even though I used software's in ubuntu. 
Finally after 2 days.

The solution:
You can install dual boot.

- But you have to back up all your data. First install windows and
  delete all partions(don't delete your system reserved).
- In my case off 500Gb hardisk I had 465Gb of unallocated space after deleting all the partition.
- Create a partition of the size you want to use for
  windows. And leave your desired unallocated space for ubuntu.(In my
  case I created 400Gb of partition for windows and 65Gb for ubuntu).

[My hard disk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7xYN.jpg)

After installing windows. Now install ubuntu. You can find the unallocated free space. And it's usable now.
Even the option install Ubuntu alongside  windows also appear now.

[my ubuntu installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfk6.jpg)

You can create your partitions in windows if you want.